# Adding a second src to video_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5-video, erb

In rails I am facing some difficulties adding a second video source for this video_tag. The video_tag isn't documented as well as it could be for me to solve this, and was hoping for some input.

```
<%= video_tag "demo_video.mp4", :size => "800x450", :controls => true, :type => "video/mp4" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're not looking at the right documentation. Try this link: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_tag. You can see that the documentation states:

> If sources is a string, a single video tag will be returned. If sources is an array, a video tag with nested source tags for each source will be returned. The sources can be full paths or files that exists in your public videos directory.

So your code might look like:

```
<%= video_tag ["demo_video.mp4", "demo_video2.mp4"], :size => "800x450", :controls => true, :type => "video/mp4" %>
```

Comment: Thanks dude! I appreciate it.

Comment: What if you need to specify different `type` for each source?

Comment: @fguillen Not sure. You'll probably have a lot better luck by making a new question. Good luck!